# Can I restore an iPhone backup and keep the original version of apps (and not download the latest available one from the AppStore)?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I have an iPhone backup created while it was running iOS 10, and want to restore it onto a new iPhone which is running iOS 12. I'd like to keep the **original** versions of the iOS apps instead of upgrading them to the latest available from the App Store.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 3):

This used to be possible up to iTunes 12.6
Individual .ipa files for each app were stored on the user's local computer & could be restored to a new device [assuming they were capable of running on it].

Since 12.7, iTunes no longer keeps copies of .ipa files & after a new device install, apps are downloaded direct from the App Store - these will always be latest versions.

Apple did keep a special corporate version of iTunes available - currently 12.6.5 - via this link; [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/HT208079) but it requires you already have the .ipa files on your computer, or can pull them from the old device. I haven't tried this as a working method in a long time so can't quite recall the precise steps needed.

It also will not run under Mojave, so is quite a limited resource.